# How to load spline scene without it blocking the main thread in react

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, spline

i built a landing page using react and then decided to add a spline scene in the home page, it works pretty fine except when it's being loaded, at that time the entire page freezes and when i click on any button it doesn't work until the scene is fully loaded then everything works fine.

First of all i thought the problem was with react so i made another project with vanilla js and tried it there, but that didn't work, i tried lazy loading with react and that didn't work, i tried promisses and a web worker, i tried putting the scene in another iframe and see if it works but it didn't, finally i tried putting on a loading page with simple css animations, but the problem is the scene freezes the css as well so the loading page looks stuck.

i just want to have a smooth loading experience for users once they enter the landing page

this is my spline scene component code:

import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';

export const HomeScene = () => {
return (

);
}

Answer (score 0):

There are some big optimization issues with Spline scene from what I saw so far. I haven't tried to implement Spline with React however, I did try to make very basic and simple landing page combining Webflow with Spline by utilizing Spline Scene from Webflow.

This gave me huge bumps in CPU and Power usage on desktop. Chrome was freezing even with simple Spline animation and as you mentioned, user experience was awful.

From what I saw around the web, there should be some major scene optimization done within Spline, but I am not familiar of how to approach it and what to change. Even on some tutorial videos I have seen that their pc was lagging when importing scene within Webflow (which have official component called "Spline Scene" to implement this).

Your React code should not be a problem here.

Answer (score -1):

Using lazy loading can potentially help resolve your issue. Make sure you implement lazy loading for the spline scene. This way, the scene will be loaded only when it's needed, reducing the likelihood of the page freezing during initial load.

Comment: i tried React.lazy() and React.Suspense(), but the problem seems to stay the same, maybe I'm implementing them wrong\/

Comment: It seems like you haven't properly implemented code splitting. Please review your code to ensure that you're using splitting correctly. This issue may be arising from improper splitting.